# How to get a custom annotation to change variables value?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, annotations

I am currently using hibernate validators to validate fields in my bean. One of the variables is an email address which has validations :

```
  @Email(message = "{notWellFormed}")
  @Size(max = 30, message = "{maxLength}")
  @NotBlank(message = "{required}")
  String email;
```

However, these annotations do not let me specify what needs to be done in case of leading/trailing white space. The requirement now is to trim the leading/trailing whitespace and carry on. I have googled for java custom annotations but none of the examples use annotations to change a variables value. What can I do, so that the leading and trailing white spaces are taken care of ?

I wrote a custom *validator* annotation, annotated my field with is `@CutWhiteSpace` and change the value in the isValid method, but that didnt work so I am obviously not understanding something.

Comment: does [this](http://www.journaldev.com/2668/spring-mvc-form-validation-example-using-annotation-and-custom-validator-implementation) help you

Comment: Since your email address is a string, I would suggest using an init binder with `StringTrimmerEditor`.  This would go in your controller, and would trim the string prior to the value being set in the model.

Comment: @CodeChimp That helps. Is there a way an action could be performed on a variable using annotations ? For ex., if all email values needed to be appended with an at.domain.com

Comment: By action, do you mean like having something on the UI/client happen, like auto-filling in the `@domain.com` part?  If so the answer is 'no'.  However, if you mean having some custom annotation to check your version of an email, certainly!  You will want to look up `ConstraintValidator` and `@Constraint`.  The first is used to write the validator for your constraint, the latter is the annotation used to write a custom JSR-303 validation annotation.

Comment: @CodeChimp I meant, to do what I am asking in the question. If the user submits '  a@b.com' then my annotation would cut the leading white space and submit 'a@b.com' to the controller. A validating annotation will simply refuse this string. Trimming of the white space is what I meant by performing an action. Cheers

Comment: @happybuddha In Java Strings are immutable.  So, although one could create a custom JSR-303 annotation with the accompanying ConstraintValidator, I don't think you have any way to do anything with the string once its in the validator.  Not unless you wrapped it somehow in another object, then you could chang the wrapper object.  But then you would probably have to write custom Init Binders anyway, in which case you might as well leave it a String and use the `StringTrimmerEditor`.